# Bounded type in Generics not working on extending another bounded type

Tags: java, generics, bounded-types

I am trying to extend the bounded type T2 to use T1 as shown in the code below :

```
class TestMultiBoundedTypes<T1 extends Number, T2 extends T1>{
T1 a;
T2 b;
void set(T1 x, T2 y)
{
    a = x;
    b = y;
}
T1 getNum1()
{
    return a;
}
T2 getNum2()
{
    return b;
}   
}
class MultiBoundedTypes
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    TestMultiBoundedTypes<Integer, Double> ob = new TestMultiBoundedTypes<Integer, Double>();
    ob.set(new Integer(5), new Double(5.23));
    System.out.println("Number1 = "+ob.getNum1());
    System.out.println("Number2 = "+ob.getNum2());
}
}
```

Since I have made bounded type T2 extend the bounded type T1, therefore I expect T2 to accept any class type that is Number or any subclass of Number. I have passed Double class to T2 but I get an error :

[image]

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: `T2 extends T1` but `Double` doesn't extend `Integer` (which is set to `T1`).

Comment: You have defined T2 as Double to extend T1 as Integer. If you want T1 to be Number you have to say so.

Answer (score 0):

> Since I have made bounded type T2 extend the bounded type T1, therefore I expect T2 to accept any class type that is Number or any subclass of Number.

Wrong assumption. In order to get this behavior, you should declare it as :

```
class TestMultiBoundedTypes<T1 extends Number, T2 extends Number>
```

With your original declaration of `TestMultiBoundedTypes`, if you pass an `Integer` as the first type, the second type must be `Integer` or any sub-type of `Integer` (and since `Integer` is final, that means it must be `Integer`).

Therefore

```
TestMultiBoundedTypes<Integer, Integer> ob = new TestMultiBoundedTypes<Integer, Integer>();
```

would pass compilation, but

```
TestMultiBoundedTypes<Integer, Double> ob = new TestMultiBoundedTypes<Integer, Double>();
```

would not.

Answer (score 0):

"T2 extends T1" means that T2 must be either the same type as T1, or a type derived from T1.  (More restricted than T1.)  But `Double` is not derived from `Integer`.  That's where you are going wrong.

You could try

```
    TestMultiBoundedTypes<Number,Double> ob = new TestMultiBoundedTypes<>();
```

since `Double` is derived from `Number`, and then you could still do

```
    ob.set( new Integer( 5 ), new Double( 5.23 ) );
```

Because `Integer` is a `Number`, but if you try to access `ob.a` you will notice that it is of type `Number`, which is not very useful.

Comment: a poor approach for getting values as a `Number` type

Comment: @AndrewTobilko You presume that the OP wants to get values.  All he wants is to understand how bounded types work.  My answer does the best job at explaining that.  The usefulness of the resulting class is irrelevant.  In any case, my answer already anticipates that it is useless.